# changing a href to forward method

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How can I change normal link `<a href="listNotes.jsp">List all entries</a>`
 in JSP

to to forwarding method `forward("listNotes.jsp", request, response);`

```
protected void forward(String JSPFileName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher(JSPFileName).forward(request, response);
}
```

?

some way using forms?

Comment: A server-side forward is independent of the link. Do you just want the `href` to lead to a servlet, rather than a JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the link URL match the URL pattern of the servlet

E.g.

```
<a href="forward/listnotes.jsp">
```

with a servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/forward/*` and does the following job in the `doGet()` method, assuming that you'd like to hide the JSP file in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent direct access:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF" + request.getPathInfo()).forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a FORM and put your href tags inside that and connect the tag to a form submit. And in your form action, point it to a servlet. (Actually, you can even point your href directly to your servlet) IN the servlet doPost or doGet method, you can call the forward method.

So code will look something like

FORM action="/MyForwardServlet"

a href="#" action="/MyForwardServlet"

And in your MyFOrwardServlet.doPost

doPost(HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse response) {

// call your forward method or put that code inline here.
}